# Remove slide number from title slide with Beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

I want to remove the slide number from the first slide in my LaTeX presentation made with Beamer. I'm using `maketitle` to create the first slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{My Presentation Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{July 28, 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\end{document}
```

Is there any way ensure that a slide number does appear on the title slide? Oddly enough, I can't find a solution to this question online when one uses `\maketitle`. Thanks!

Comment: By default beamer won't show a frame number. If your presentation shows one, than whatever theme you use adds it. How to remove it will depend on your theme. Please always test your [mre] to ensure it reproduces the problem.